# How can you do a $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] inside an echo command?

Tags: php

I really thought I had this one down, but for some reason inside the echo it doesn't want to perform the command.  It just echo's it to the web page url.

```
http://localhost/<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']); ?>

<?php 
  echo' <form name="action" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']); ?>" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
    </form>';
?>
```

I was going to try and have it post to self and then if there is post data then:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['action'])){ 
  //do something here
}
```

I tried to break the echo also:

```
echo "  <form name='action' action=".<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>." method="post">
         <input type='text' name='name'><br>
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form'><br>
       </form>";
```

Comment: PHP is also not recursively embeddable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an echo statement inside of another php/echo statement. You should only do that if you've broken out of php:

```
echo "  <form name='action' action=".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])." method="post">
     <input type='text' name='name'><br>
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form'><br>
   </form>";
```

or outside of PHP:

```
?>
<form name='action' action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<input type='text' name='name'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form'><br>
</form>
<?php
```

Comment: I was doing an If {} Else{} with php, so how can I make this work?  Would I have to ?> echo...

Comment: I updated my answer with how you can do it outside of PHP. So you can surround the second part with the If/Else